# aws s3 rename directory (object)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to rename directory in amazon aws s3 bucket. I know that there is no such things like directory in aws s3 everything is object

I have directory structure like

```
abc/
   aaa
   bbb
```

And Now I am trying to rename it by

```
  $s3->copyObject(array(
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key' => $newName,
        'CopySource' => "{$bucket}/{$currentObj}",
  ));
```

and then delete existing, it create new object with new name,the problem is that

when I rename the `abc` to something else like `demo` it just create new object with name `demo` which is empty

I am also aware that why `demo` is empty because there were three different object

```
abc/
abc/aaa
abc/bbb
```

Now to rename them all with one request, is there something like `copyMatchingObjects`? I mean we have `deleteMatchingObjects`

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot rename them all in one API call. The best you can do is probably:

- copy abc/aaa to demo/aaa
- copy abc/bbb to demo/bbb
- delete abc/aaa
- delete abc/bbb
- delete abc/ (if it actually exists)

In particular, there is typically no need to create demo/.